# SQL order by total of number of value by rows

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Is there a way to return total of column contain value in row to use it for order by
example :

```
id  | title         | body_text_1           | body_text_2           | body_text_3           |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1   |  History      | book of History       | movies                | Image                 |
2   |  Sport        | history               | book                  | Audio                 |
3   |  Cinema       | History               | History               | History               |
4   |  History      | classic               | History               | Audio                 |
```

I'm using LIKE %value% If I search for word ***History***
The result show id 3 as the 1st one because It has history in 3 column

the 2nd will be 1 and 4 because it has history in 2 columns

the last one will be 2 because it has history only in one column

result :

```
3
1
4
2
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add the booleans in an `order by`:

```
order by (title = 'History') + (body_text_1 = 'History') +  (body_text_2 = 'History') + (body_text_34 = 'History') desc
```

Comment: is return the same result is that because I'm using like %value%

Comment: @im-learning . . . you can use whatever expressions are appropriate.  This addresses the question you *originally* asked.